# How to split string in array in two?

Tags: ruby, string

I currently have a single column CSV file such as: `["firstname lastname", "firstname lastname", ...]`.

I would like to create a CSV file such as `["f.lastname", "f.lastname"...]`; `f` being the first letter of the firstname.

Any idea how I should do that ?

**update**

Ok well, I feel that I am close thanks to you guys, here's what I got so far :

```
  require 'csv'
  filename = CSV.read("mails.csv")
  mails = []
  CSV.foreach(filename) do |col|
   mails << filename.map { |n| n.sub(/\A(\w)\w* (\w+)\z/, '\1. \2') }
  end
  puts mails.to_s
```

But I still get an error.

**update2**

Ok this works just fine :

```
require 'csv'
mails = []
CSV.foreach('mails.csv', :headers => false) do |row|
  mails << row.map(&:split).map{|f,l| "#{f[0]}.#{l}@mail.com" }
end
File.open("mails_final.csv", 'w') {|f| f.puts mails }
puts mails.to_s
```

Thanks a lot to all of you ;)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1254:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without using regular expression:

```
ary = ["firstname lastname", "firstname lastname"]
ary.map(&:split).map{|f, l| "#{f[0]}. #{l}" }
#=> ["f. lastname", "f. lastname"]
```

Comment: Okay it works, just one thing, how do I delete the space between f. and lastname for example ?

Update : Nevermind, I managed to do it ;) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
ary = ["firstname lastname", "firstname lastname"]
ary.map{|a| e=a.split(" "); e[0][0]+"."+e[1]}
#=> ["f.lastname", "f.lastname"]
```

You need to modify your this following code:--

```
CSV.foreach(filename) do |col|
  mails << filename.map { |n| n.sub(/\A(\w)\w* (\w+)\z/, '\1. \2') }
end
```

to match something like the following:--

```
CSV.foreach(path_to_csv_file/mails.csv, headers: true/false) do |row|
  # row is kind _of CSV::Row, do not use filename.map => causing error
  mails << row.to_hash.map { |n| n.sub(/\A(\w)\w* (\w+)\z/, '\1. \2') }
end
```

Comment: Hm I get this : `test.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `to_hash' for ["Able Parris"]:Array (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do that way:

```
array = ["firstname lastname", "firstname lastname"]
array.map { |n| "#{n[0]}.#{n.split[1]}" }
```